# Separate vue.js template into files

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm wondering if there is a way in Vue.js to make this code :

```
<template v-if="type === 'login'">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter your username" key="username-input">
</template>

<template v-if="type === 'subscribe'">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter your email address" key="email-input">
</template>
```

Looks something like this:

```
<template type="login" />

<template type="subscribe" />

<template id="login">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter your username" key="username-input">
</template>

<template id="subscribe">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter your email address" key="email-input">
</template>
```

so we can call template by their Ids

In my case I wanted to use it in events :

```
<template v-if="type === 'new_user'">
 <span>welcome {{ username }}</span>
</template>

<template v-if="type === 'user_confiremd'">
 <span>You have full access {{ username }}</span>
</template>
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
<template v-for="event in events" :event="event" />
```

Comment: Why not just using reusable components via [Single File Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)?

Comment: Can you explain it in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to conditionally use some templates, here's an example of how [Vue2's dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) could be used:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    type: 'login',
    email: 'email.sync@example.com',
    dataFromChildren: {parentData: {email: 'vbind@example.com'}}
  },
  components: {
    login: {
      template: '#login',
      props: ['email'],
      data: function() { return { watchedEmail: this.email } },
      watch: { watchedEmail: function() { this.$emit('update:email', this.watchedEmail); } }
    },
    subscribe: {
      template: '#subscribe',
      props: ['parentData']
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="login">
  <div>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input placeholder="Enter your username" key="username-input" v-model="watchedEmail">
  </div>
</template>

<template id="subscribe">
  <div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input placeholder="Enter your email address" key="email-input" v-model="parentData.email">
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <component v-bind:is="type" :email.sync="email" v-bind="dataFromChildren"></component>

  <hr>
  <button @click="type = 'login'">login template</button>
  <button @click="type = 'subscribe'">subscribe template</button>
  
  <p>Edited via e-mail.sync [login component] (good practice): {{ email }}</p>
  <p>Edited via nested props [subscribe component] (bad practice): {{ dataFromChildren }}</p>
</div>
```

One drawback I see here is that your templates must have a single root component (otherwise you would get the error *Component template should contain exactly one root element.*), which is a requirement from Vue.

Another thing is that the templates are actual components, so to pass data to them you have to have props and all. The code above shows **two ways** of sending that data and getting it back. I recommend the `:e-mail.sync`  alternative, it is the best practice in this case.

Comment: how to pass variable to the template ?

Comment: I added an example of passing and getting variables to the templates. If you just want passing (and not getting), it could be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

It's sound like start of bad practices...

You need to create two components and use the relevantic by the type variable.

You can controll the component by routing or just dynamic component.

Somthing like this:

```
<component :is="type" />
```

Refernces:

- [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)
- [Routing in Vue js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html)

Comment: I don't like this approach creating many components not good idea

Comment: @bader If you were to say this on the registration form and logging in there was something in your words.
When it comes to 2 different forms in this functionality it is needed. If you do not see it then go back to using jquery...